# Applying select() to create new data frame with three variables

Tags: r

After previewing and cleaning your data, you determine what variables are most relevant to your analysis. Your main focus is on Rating, Cocoa.Percent, and Bean.Type. You decide to use the `select()` function to create a new data frame with only these three variables.

Assume the first part of your code is:

```
trimmed_flavors_df <- flavors_df %>%
```

Add the code chunk that lets you select the three variables.

My code :

```
select(flavors_df, rating,cocoa.percent,bean.type)
```

Result:

> Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'rating' not found
> Calls: %>% ... select_vars_ ->  -> lapply -> FUN -> eval -> eval

I tried this and that and final exhausted for not finding the answer. Please help me

Comment: R is case sensitive so it might have to be Rating, Cocoa.Percent, etc., like it's written in the homework question you were given :-)

Comment: I just tried and this is the error message I received....Error: All select() inputs must resolve to integer column positions.
The following do not:
*  flavors_df

Comment: Thank you for reminding me about case sensitive R is case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

You can also make sure that you're not repeating a call for the dataframe twice, for example...

**What will not work:**

```
trimmed_flavors_df <- flavors_df %>% select(flavors_df, rating,cocoa.percent,bean.type)
```

**What will work**

```
trimmed_flavors_df <- select(flavors_df, rating,cocoa.percent,bean.type)
```

or alternatively

```
trimmed_flavors_df <- flavors_df %>% select(rating,cocoa.percent,bean.type)
```

Notice removal of "flavors_df" from within the select() brackets, or without the pipe.

Comment: OMG.. it worked ...select( Rating,Cocoa.Percent,Bean.Type)......thanks you so much

Comment: Hi Sage Wyatt.......Can you please answer my question.....why my code didn't work? Did I mention flavors_df twice ( in the pipe) and in select( )....is this the reason or something else?

Comment: Glad to help! You said the exactly correct reason. Only call the data once. Imagine I wanted you to find a banana I hid in a box labelled "fruit" in a room called "storage", in a building called "factory". I might be able to give you a list that says "factory, storage, banana" and you would understand that the clues get more and more specific. R understands things in a hierarchical nature like this. But if I gave you a list that says "factory, factory, storage, banana", within the factory you would be running around all day to find a room also called "factory", and never find the banana!